# A short puzzle especially for social isolation time

Tags: word, knowledge, lateral-thinking

Solve the following analogy. ":" means "is to" and "::" means "as".
[image]

Text only:

> story with anopia : smell :: story with hyperosmia : ?

Hint

> to find the correct answer in the analogy, you have to fit those conditions into specific stories,(two distinct stories), this is the knowledge part. What are the "stories" that are usually visible (and audible)?

Comment: Is it possible to transcribe this? Struggling to read it :)

Comment: @Beastly text provided

Comment: Why the text only version hidden in a spoiler? is it too a hint?

Comment: @Always Confused, As far as I remember, somebody asked for that version. I did not make that spoiler, a third somebody did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that:

> Story with anopia: smell. Story with hyperosmia: **sight**

Reason:

> Anopia means a defect in sight, while hyperosmia is a heightened sense of smell. So you just change the sense smell to sight and you get the answer

Comment: UnidentifiedX, unfortunately not. To be honest, I don't even think that the "reason" is logical.

Comment: rot13(V jbhyq guvax vg'f vairefr nf svefg bar vf "pna'g frr:fzryy" - fb frpbaq jbhyq or "fzryy jryy:oyvaq sbyq")

Comment: rot13(Be fbzrguvat ryfr. V guvax jr unir gb ernyvmr, gung sbe rknzcyr mreb k : l :: znal l : ? qbrf abg unir na "bhg bs pbagrkg", havirefnyyl pbeerpg ybtvpny nafjre. Purpx gur gntf gb cebprrq.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if my answers are not high standard but I guessing it may be

> SWELL

Because

> 1. Osmosis means an absorbtion phenomenon which makes thing swell.
>  2. Anopia (blindness) will take help of more smell. Thus a "more osmosis" (hyperosmia) (Tag: lateral thinking) will make more swelling.
>  3. Social isolation aka Lockdown has made some people obese aka swolen
>  4. Smell rhymes with swell.

Comment: this is incorrect.